# Driveimage xml hard drive copy after back up?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, clone, xml, windows-backup

I started by trying to restore my system from a system image but later found out that didn’t include a copy of the actual operating system so that wasn’t helpful.

Edited to add: I also tried to just copy it drive to drive in driveimage xml but that didn’t work Id just get a “Copying ‘C:’ to ‘Disk1#2’ failed.” Pop up with no further explanation whatsoever.

Edited for clarity. Thanks so far everyone.

I did a backup that got interrupted with drive image xml so I just deleted everything and retried copying the disc over cause I didn’t trust whether I’d figure out how to verify everything properly as per the comments suggestion.

It still just shows the “unable to copy” error with no explanation. I’m also unable to reformat the destination drive to GBR. How do I do that?

Edit: I used aomei partition assistant to reformat the destination drive to GBR and let it restart my computer to complete it.

The drive to drive transfer seems to be working after I reformatted the destination drive to GBR! I don’t understand why that works at all and would love to know if anyone wants to explain that to me! I got that idea from another post on here thanks community!!

**So why does destination drive format matter when attempting a drive to drive transfer and why did it have to be a different format than the original drive to start the transfer?**

And thanks for the reminder this isn’t a comedy blog and putting in references and jokes just makes things really confusing!! The transfer is about a quarter done so I’ll check back once it’s finished and tested to update and/or ask further questions.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear what you' asking. IMO it's word salad.

Comment: Simply put, I would *not* trust a vital disk image that was interrupted. DriveImage XML allows you to review everything stored, but I don't remember if it has a *verify* feature. On something as important as moving the entire disk, I'd use software such as old, free, Macrium Reflct 8, turn on *verify* image, and then *examine* the image to try to open a few of the files in each partition. Having seen one instance of a development site relying on images that **had all been found to have failed**, I've become adverse to taking chances.

Comment: Don't try to be funny, try to be clear and precise. Your question jumps around a bit and lacks focus. Please edit your question, make sure you state your issue, the steps leading up to it, any symptoms, and a precise list of each thing you've tried.